# Why other data no updated except fileupload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    con.Open();
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/RegisterPhoto") + "/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Registration SET Pincode='" + pin.Text + "', Gender='" + gender.SelectedValue + "', Mstatus='" + ms.SelectedValue + "', Lstatus='" + ls.SelectedValue + "', Address='" + address.Text + "', AdharNumber='" + adhaar.Text + "', ContactNumber='" + phone.Text + "', Email='" + email.Text + "', ProfilePhoto='" + FileUpload1.FileName + "' WHERE Username='" + Session["user"] + "'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx");
    con.Close();
}
else
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Registration SET Pincode='" + pin.Text + "', Gender='" + gender.SelectedValue + "', Mstatus='" + ms.SelectedValue + "', Lstatus='" + ls.SelectedValue + "', Address='" + address.Text + "', AdharNumber='" + adhaar.Text + "', ContactNumber='" + phone.Text + "', Email='" + email.Text + "' WHERE Username='" + Session["user"] + "'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx");
    con.Close();
}
```

I want to develop functionality where if a user updates their data along with a profile picture the if() part will execute. If a user only update their textual data the else part will execute.

I run it, when I upload image it will upload it into db. too. But if I update some text data along with image  then only image updated.

And if I only update text data so nothing updated.

I do not know what's going on, there is no error thrown.

Comment: Yikes, this is scary. It's **NEVER** okay to use string concatenation to put data into an SQL query like that. Of lesser concern but still worth mentioning, it's also poor practice to try to reuse the same connection object. You really should create a new SqlConnection nearly every time you run a query.

Comment: Please feel free to let know if you have any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, we do need to deal with sql injection here.

This explains why:

[image]

So, assuming a button click, then I suggest code like this:

```
    protected void cmdDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd;

        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string ProfilePic = Server.MapPath(@"~//RegisterPhoto/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(ProfilePic);

            cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Registration ProfilePhoto = @ProfilePic
                              WHERE Username = @User";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProfilePick", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ProfilePic;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["user"];
            General.MyRstE(cmd);
        }


        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Registration SET Pincode = @pin
                          Gender = @Gender, Mstatus = @Mstatus,
                          Lstatus = @Lstatus,
                          Address = @Address, AdharNumber = @Adharr,
                          ContactNumber = @ContactNumber, 
                          Email = @Email
                          WHERE Username = @User";

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@pin", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = pin.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gender", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = gender.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Mstatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ms.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Lstatus", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ls.SelectedValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = address.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Adharr", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = adhaar.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = phone.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = email.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["user"];
        General.MyRstE(cmd);

        Response.Redirect("Profile.aspx");
    }
```

Your logic to check for a new file up-load should work, and above shows code to save the new profile picture path.

However, since each and every time you wish to re-save the profile data, then we only require ONE copy of that code.

And to save some keyboarding here, I have a general code routine called MyRstE which is to simple execute a SQL command object.

That code is this:

```
    public static void MyRstE(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, that's really little hard to understand but yeah I got its crux. Thank you sir..